# How can I trigger the Spotify Play button to play when I click a link that triggers it to display?

Tags: jquery, html, spotify

Here is the jQuery code that displays the Spotify Play button when I click the link that says "Rock the house!"

```
$(function() {
$('#partystart').toggle(function () {
    $(".fadeIn").addClass("party");
    $("#musicbox").slideDown("300");
    $("#partystart").html("<a id='partystart'>Take a break</a>");
}, function () {
    $(".fadeIn").removeClass("party");
    $(".fadeIn").addClass("fullopacity");
    $("#musicbox").slideUp("300");
    $("#partystart").html("<a id='partystart'>&#9650; Rock the house!</a>");
});
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="partybox" >
    <iframe id="musicbox" style="margin-top: -2px; display: none;" src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:3QMLpta0AmeJLpWNmeyC6B#0:12" width="250" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
    <a id="partystart">&#9650; Rock the house!</a>
</div>
```

Here is an example that allows you to click on a circle to play the track rather than the play button inside the actual Spotify Play button: http://spotifymusic.tumblr.com/

Also, I put `#0:12` at the end of the URI for the song to get it to start playing at 0:12 seconds in, but it doesn't seem to work.  What am I doing wrong there?

Thanks!

Comment: by the way, I added the href to trigger the track as follows:
<a href="spotify:track:3QMLpta0AmeJLpWNmeyC6B" id="partystart">&#9650; Rock the house!</a>

The issue is that it only triggers the track to play when I don't have the jquery involved

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a spotify account and don't plan to make one, but the following solution should work, you'll just need to do a little investigation.

The Spotify iFrame has a click event attachted to .play-pause-btn (I think). You need to activate the click event for playback to start. It would be something like this:

```
$("#musicbox").contents().find("div.play-pause-btn").click();
```

Adding it with the rest of your code:

```
$('#partystart').toggle(function () {
    $(".fadeIn").addClass("party");
    $("#musicbox").slideDown("300");
    $("#partystart").html("<a id='partystart'>Take a break</a>");
    $("#musicbox").contents().find("div.play-pause-btn").click();
}, function () {
    $(".fadeIn").removeClass("party");
    $(".fadeIn").addClass("fullopacity");
    $("#musicbox").slideUp("300");
    $("#partystart").html("<a id='partystart'>&#9650; Rock the house!</a>");
});
});
```

If it doesn't work, you'll need to determine which item has the click event on it.