# How to play spotify button with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spotify

I write app where user can listen other user playlists from spotify.
I want trigger spotify play button when i click on specific track.

On my playlist show page i have spotify play button

```
  <iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:trackset:<%= @playlist.name %>:<%= @playlist.tracks.first.track_number %>" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

With jquery a can replace iframe src attribute, but then i always must click on this spotify play button to play music.

```
  $( ".trackline" ).click(function() {
    var src = $('iframe').attr('src');
    var newsrc = $(this).attr('data-tracknumber');
    $('iframe').attr("src", newsrc);
  });
```

I try solve this with this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811903/how-can-i-trigger-the-spotify-play-button-to-play-when-i-click-a-link-that-trigg)
Next i read about that spotify cant allow trigger this button.
But then i found this site [Playlists.net](http://playlists.net/instrumental-sentimentum).
On this site you can click on track and then this automatic play on spotify play button.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use breakpoints and debug your manual click. I think you are firing the click event for the wrong element (".trackline").